# Django: updating ManyToManyField on save

Tags: python, django

I have a Book model which has a many-to-many field Author.  If I merge two books, I want to make sure that the merged book has only unique authors, no doubles.  I thought the best way to achieve this was to override the save() method, and so far I've come to this model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField()

    def save(self):
        authors_new = []
        authors = self.authors.all()
        for author in authors:
            if author not in authors_new:
                authors_new.append(author)
        self.authors = authors_new           #This won't work
        super(Book, self).save()
```

The penultimate line obviously doesn't work, but I just can't seem to get the syntax right.  I think what I want to achieve is pretty obvious, though.  Anyone any idea what the right syntax is?

**Edit 1:**

To explain the merge: I must say I don’t fully understand the code (written by someone else - the merge takes places over several functions), so showing it here won’t help me.  What it does is this: say there’s two books in the database that are obviously the same. The first book has

```
title= “Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone”
author=“JK Rowling”
year=1999
```

and the other book has

```
title=“Harry Potter (book 1)”
author=“JK Rowling” 
pages=320
```

When you merge you need to chose which book is the primary book.  If I’d chose the first one to be primary, the merge should end up as

```
title=“Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone”
author=“JK Rowling”
year=1999
pages=320
```

Problem is the merge ends up with author=“JK Rowling” **twice**  I thought that I could take out the duplicates in the save function.

**Edit 2:**

The merge takes places in this function, that I haven't written:

```
def merge_model_objects(primary_object, *alias_objects):
    # Use this function to merge model objects and migrate all of 
    # the related fields from the alias objects to the primary object.

    for alias_object in alias_objects:
        meta = alias_object._meta
        for related_object in meta.get_all_related_objects():
            alias_varname = related_object.get_accessor_name()
            obj_varname = related_object.field.name
            related_objects = getattr(alias_object, alias_varname)
            for obj in related_objects.all():
                if getattr(obj, 'do_not_merge', False):
                    continue
                setattr(obj, obj_varname, primary_object)
                obj.save()

        related_objects = meta.get_all_related_many_to_many_objects()
        for related_many_object in related_objects:
            alias_varname = related_many_object.get_accessor_name()
            obj_varname = related_many_object.field.name

            if alias_varname is not None:
                # standard case
                related_many_objects = getattr(
                    alias_object, alias_varname).all()
            else:
                # special case, symmetrical relation, no reverse accessor
                related_many_objects = getattr(alias_object, obj_varname).all()
            for obj in related_many_objects.all():
                getattr(obj, obj_varname).remove(alias_object)
                getattr(obj, obj_varname).add(primary_object)

        alias_object.delete()
    primary_object.save()
    return primary_object
```

This is quite a general function and can merge more than two objects, but if I merge Book 1 (= primary_object) and Book 2 (= alias_object) it will save it as a book with author="JK Rowling" **twice**.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it is obvious. What do you mean by "merging" two books? Why would you have duplicates?

Comment: There might be duplicates indeed, different people add books to the database.  If books are merged I want to make sure every author is only added once to the book.

Comment: I think that django ManyToManyField already costraints unique relations. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried a normal merge, but if both books before the merge have the same author, the author is just added twice to the new merged book.  I tried something like `models.ManyToManyField(unique=True)` but I get the message _ManyToManyFields cannot be unique_

Comment: Unique in ManyToMany would not make sense, since its a ManyToMany, you could try unique_together

Comment: You should explain what a "normal merge" actually is. *Show the code* for how you're merging books. Normally, as others have said, Django won't add an item to a M2M if it is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Django represents many to many fields as sets. So you would probably want to do something like

```
self.authors = self.authors.union(other_model.authors)
```

[Python sets are collections of unique, unordered objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).